# Andorid Application sending notifications to a group of users and allowing replys

Tags: android

I have been researching for a way to send notifications to a specific group of users from within my application and have found this can be done through Google Firebase. But for the application I am creating I need to know how many of these users can attend an event - i.e. 'yes' or 'no' which the organizer of the event will need to know. So my question is can this be achieved or any advice on a way I might do this?

Thanks, able

Comment: Yes, you can do it with firebase. The group of people should be subscribed to the topic on client side, after that you can send data notification with details and inside your app show notification with corresponding PendingIntents (yes/no). PendingIntent should fire broadcast message to trigger your code to send a reply.

Comment: @ViktorYakunin Thanks for the reply, just what I was looking for. On a side note, would it  be possible to send notifications without using the firebase console. Could a notification message be created from within the app and use the Firebase API to send this notification?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase can be used to send notifications to users. You can send to specific groups using firebase topics. The reply from the users can be send back to your server using standard client-server communication.